# windows registry storage best practice

Tags: windows, installation

**Background**

I've recently been shunted into the world of windows programming and I'm still trying to find my way around the best practices and ways of doing things. So I was just hoping for some pointers on use of the registry

Not particularly relevant but the background is that I am creating an installer in Golang, a couple of points to get out the way on that:

- I am aware MSI's would usually be best practice for an installer (I have my reasons for going custom exe)
- I know there are more obvious language choices than golang, just go with it

**Current registry use**

As part of the install process, I store several pieces of data in the registry:

**run once commands:**

> *Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\RunOnce*

I create a few entries here: to restart the process after a system reboot and to delete some temp files on reboot after uninstall

**an uninstall entry:**

> *Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\Windows\CurrentVersion\Uninstall\Vendor
>   Product*

Content here is the same as an MSI would create, I was careful not to create any additional custom fields here (all static data until uninstall)

**an application entry:**

> *Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Vendor\Product*

I store some additional data about the installation here, some of which is needed for uninstall such as state info from before installation (again all static content)

**a temporary entry:**

> *Computer\HKEY_CURRENT_USER\SOFTWARE\Vendor\Product*

I store some temporary data here which can include some sensitive user entered data (usernames/passwords). I run some symmetric encryption to obscure the data though my understanding is this is area of the registry is encrypted so only the user could access anyway (would like confirmation on that)
This data is used to resume after restart and then deleted

**Questions**

1. I'm looking for confirmation / corrections on my current use of the registry?
2. I now have need to pass some data between an application and a running service, this data would be updated every 1-2 minutes and would be a few bytes of JSON. Does the registry seem like a reasonable place to store variable data like this? If so is there a particular place that better for variable data - I was going to add it to:
   *Computer\HKEY_LOCAL_MACHINE\SOFTWARE\Vendor\Product*

Answer (score 2, accepted):

HCKU isn't encrypted to my knowledge. It's stored in a file called NTUser.dat and could be loaded as a hive under HKEY_USERS and visible to other processes with sufficient rights to do so.

You would need to open up the rights to HKLM\SOFTWARE\Vendor\Product if you expect a user priv process to be able to write to it.  If you want to pass data to a service you might want to use some sort of IPC pipe to do so.  Not sure what's available in Golang for this.

Comment: Ah, I didn't consider that my service wouldn't be able to write to the registry.There are ways of piping data between apps in golang but it would require a bit of a rethink about how I'm doing things, might be easier just to write to disk somewhere. Would I be correct in thinking that if I also stored my sensitive data to a temp file under the Users AppData, that would then be encrypted

Comment: I was more worried about the client side code perms.  The service could also be an issue depending on what the service runs as.   LocalService, NetworkService, System and so on.  If you write to the users profile I wonder  how the service would know which profile to look at.  All of them?  You could write to a file under C:\ProgramData but the installer would have to set the perms on that subdir also.

Comment: Sorry for the confusion, I've mixed two things together here, to clarify: The app always runs with admin permissions and the service runs as the system user. The data that needs to be shared between the two is not sensitive. The sensitive data is a separate issue, that only needs to be accessible by the app but it should be encrypted and persistent through a system restart

Comment: Then both the app and service would have permissions to that registry key or c:\programdata\company\product directory.   You can encrypt the data yourself as bitlocker might not be enabled.  Both would be persisted across restart.

Comment: thanks for clarification Chris - I am currently encrypting myself, the problem is I have to store the key in the binary, so technically anyone can grab the key out the binary and decrypt the data - that's why I was hoping I could utilize windows encryption as a secondary - perhaps a separate question though

Comment: The default inherited permissions would allow any user to create files and subdirectories in "ProgramData\Organization\Application". However, if UserA is expected to be able to modify or delete a file created by UserB, then the permissions need to be opened up to allow it. Of course if the two users are SYSTEM and an administrator, the inherited permissions already grant full access.

Comment: Those perms never made sense to me.  The common name for that fodler is CommonAppDataFolder  not FirstUserAppDataFolder

Comment: A ProgramData subdirectory is written on behalf of a program, so in general I think it's better to restrict all modifications to the common data directory to a service or task running as "LOCAL SERVICE" or "NETWORK SERVICE", with an access control entry set on the directory for the service or task SID, i.e. "NT SERVICE\\[service-name]" (S-1-5-80-...) or "NT TASK\\[task-name]" (S-1-5-87-...). I think it's too chaotic to have multiple users concurrently modifying a common data directory. Users should be granted read-execute access, but not the ability to create and modify files and directories.